# Appending of decimals in doubles in C# that I didn't ask for

Tags: c#, double, rounding

A program I was writing had a weird output, which I boiled down to the behavior of the following code:

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        double test1 = 0.1;
        double test2 = Math.Pow(10, -4);
        double test3 = 0.1+Math.Pow(10, -4);
    }
 }
```

When I check the values of `test1`, `test2`, and `test3` in debug mode, the values of the first two variables are

`test1 = 0.1`

`test2 = 0.0001`

which is what I assigned them to be, but their sum becomes

`test3 = 0.10010000000000001`.

There appears to be an error of 10^{-17}. My questions are:

- Why does this happen?
- Can I do anything to prevent it?

Thanks.

Comment: Use `decimal` instead of `double` and see [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Thanks @Habib, I couldn't find that similar question when searching the site. I will have a look.